# SVGs showing in Chrome on a Mac but not in Chrome on Windows

Tags: css, windows, macos, sass

Has anyone experience this before? This is how it's been coded:

```
      .vm {
        position: absolute;
        top: 6em;
        left: 21.6em;
        width: 10.5em;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: $green;
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,204,51);
        color: $white;
        padding-left: 34px;
        line-height: 22px;
        background-size: 22px 22px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 7px 0px;
        background-image: url(../images/_vmware.svg);
      }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like strange behaviour. I know IE 11 is supported... but Windows Chrome!  Here is a great article that has helped me in the past with SVGs, perhaps consider using DATA URI https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 0):

When i have to use svg i use an icon font generator 
(like http://fontello.com/ but its not the only one)

If your svg is too complicated to make a font, you should instead use the svg tag that is better supported by browsers
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

Comment: Yes, I'm actually already using Font Awesome. I don't think that's it, but thanks. I also changed the unit of measurement for the background-size from PXs to EMs, but it still doesn't work :/